# Is there a specific word or term for the full circle clock rotation

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I wonder whether there is any specific word for the full circle clock rotation.

I mean when any of the clock hands rotates 360 degrees clockwise.

I am using the term "lap" now, but I am not sure if this is a right word to use in this case.

I would be grateful for any variants.

Comment: 'Revolution' is the usual term. This would be found if you checked for synonyms of 'rotation' (eg at [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/rotation)), but has the more precise sense too. [CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/revolution), for instance, gives: << **revolution** noun (CIRCULAR MOVEMENT)

​
(a) [ S ] a circular movement:
The revolution of the earth around the sun was proposed by Copernicus.
​
(b) [ C ] one complete circular movement of something, for example a wheel:
Engine speed can be measured in revolutions per minute (abbreviation rpm). >>

Comment: "Revolution" is not bad but you could also say "full sweep": *After a full sweep of the minute hand, etc.*

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just refer to the amount of time that has passed?

I can't think of a context in which I would say 'one revolution/lap of the minute hand" instead of just saying one hour.

I would do the same *mutatis mutandis* for any other hand on any other clock.

Comment: I am  using this in a more technical context, so precise time is not so important.